# How to enter braces inside url in pywinauto

Tags: pywinauto

I am trying to enter url in pywinauto like this "D:\Eudora(07NOV2008).mbx" but it is skipping braces and entering like this "D:\Eudora07NOV2008.mbx", how i can fix this issue.

Comment: Are you using method .type_keys()? There is .set_edit_text() method to input the whole text as is.

Comment: Yes Vasily Ryabov, I was using type_keys(). Thanks its working perfectly for me now.

Comment: OK, now I could reach my PC to post the full answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear from question, but it seems method `.type_keys()` was used. This method tries to parse special keys with a key name in `{}` braces (like `{ENTER}`), the full list is described in the [keyboard module](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/code/pywinauto.keyboard.html) document. This method is useful for special keys combinations for any window and/or element. For the mentioned use case the code should look so:

```
.type_keys(r'D:{\}Eudora{(}07NOV2008{)}.mbx', with_spaces=True)
# the last argument tells the method to not skip spaces
```

For raw text input the more appropriate method is `.set_edit_text()` that inputs the text as is. It doesn't support special keys parsing though.

For some rare cases there is one more useful method `.set_value()` (UIA backend only).

Win32 backend contains silent text input methods `.send_chars()` and `.send_keystrokes()` that don't require even putting element into focused state.

Many of these methods are described in [the Remote Execution Guide](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/remote_execution.html).